# REST Endpoint Returns NULL in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, apexrest, failing-tests

I have a RestResource mapped to /Demo/ that I place on a Salesforce Site. The rest resource works great, including the parameters. However, in my test class I cannot get it to return anything to RestContext.response.responseBody

My first idea was that maybe it was having difficulty connecting to the endpoint, so I tried different combinations of req.requestURI (including a full URL) but it always returns the same.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Demo/*')
global class DemoController {

@HttpGet
global static List<Good__c> getRecords(){

    String location = RestContext.request.params.get('location');
    String id = RestContext.request.params.get('id');

    String qryString = 'Select Id,Name,Location__c from Good__c WHERE Id !=NULL ';

    List<Good__c> DemoGoods;

    if (!String.isBlank(location)){qryString += ' AND Location__c =: location ';}
    if (!String.isBlank(id)){qryString += ' AND id =: id ';}

    DemoGoods = Database.query(qryString);

    return DemoGoods;

}
}
```

Test Class

In this Test Class, I plan on adding System Asserts to test whether the response is 200, among other tests. However, I need to figure out why RestContext.response.responseBody is returning NULL.

```
@isTest
private class DemoControllerTest 
{

@isTest 
static void TestBehavior()
    {
        RestRequest req   = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();

        System.Debug('About to Call Request');

        req.requestURI    = '/services/apexrest/Demo';
        req.httpMethod    = 'GET';

        RestContext.request   = req;
        RestContext.response  = res; 

        DemoController.getRecords();

        System.Debug('Response Body ---' + RestContext.response.responseBody);

    }
}
```

Debug Only

```
09:18:47:005 USER_DEBUG [11]|DEBUG|About to Call Request
09:18:47:032 USER_DEBUG [21]|DEBUG|Response Body ---null
```

Here is my full execution log:

```
46.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
06:18:47.0 (729496)|EXECUTION_STARTED
06:18:47.0 (756392)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p0a000004xIgq|DemoControllerTest.TestBehavior()
06:18:47.0 (1295960)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
06:18:47.0 (1364154)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
06:18:47.0 (1394728)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
06:18:47.0 (1422420)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
06:18:47.0 (1446941)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
06:18:47.0 (1490047)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
06:18:47.0 (1518890)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:24
06:18:47.0 (1548123)|METHOD_ENTRY|[2]|01p0a000004xIgq|DemoControllerTest.DemoControllerTest()
06:18:47.0 (1563702)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
06:18:47.0 (1577783)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
06:18:47.0 (1595158)|METHOD_EXIT|[2]|DemoControllerTest
06:18:47.0 (1652324)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
06:18:47.0 (1693441)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
06:18:47.0 (1723667)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
06:18:47.0 (1803840)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[7]
06:18:47.0 (1811414)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[8]
06:18:47.0 (1870147)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:252
06:18:47.0 (1884929)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:25
06:18:47.0 (1905744)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|RestRequest.RestRequest()
06:18:47.0 (1916143)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
06:18:47.0 (1932189)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|RestRequest
06:18:47.0 (1946797)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:32
06:18:47.0 (4315658)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[8]|req|System.RestRequest|true|false
06:18:47.0 (4603166)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|req|{"headers":"0x42cc5b85","params":"0xed23ef"}|0x4e21fd8d
06:18:47.0 (4626102)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[9]
06:18:47.0 (4691893)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[9]|Bytes:156
06:18:47.0 (4709733)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[9]|Bytes:10
06:18:47.0 (4732626)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|RestResponse.RestResponse()
06:18:47.0 (4744081)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
06:18:47.0 (4760739)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|RestResponse
06:18:47.0 (4777072)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[9]|Bytes:16
06:18:47.0 (5000780)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[9]|res|System.RestResponse|true|false
06:18:47.0 (5077676)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[9]|res|{"headers":"0x16dd0c0a"}|0x7f46a765
06:18:47.0 (5096376)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[11]
06:18:47.0 (5105111)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[11]|Bytes:21
06:18:47.0 (5158443)|USER_DEBUG|[11]|DEBUG|About to Call Request
06:18:47.0 (5182146)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[13]
06:18:47.0 (5191476)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[13]|Bytes:23
06:18:47.0 (5260447)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
06:18:47.0 (5270525)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[14]|Bytes:3
06:18:47.0 (5327604)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[16]
06:18:47.0 (5421786)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[3]|System.RestContext.request|System.RestRequest|true|true
06:18:47.0 (5454040)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[4]|System.RestContext.response|System.RestResponse|true|true
06:18:47.0 (5475672)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[16]|Bytes:112
06:18:47.0 (5487565)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[16]|Bytes:5
06:18:47.0 (5506776)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|RestContext.RestContext()
06:18:47.0 (5517116)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
06:18:47.0 (5536021)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[1]|RestContext
06:18:47.0 (5696520)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[17]
06:18:47.0 (5775005)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[19]
06:18:47.0 (10858926)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[19]|Bytes:1
06:18:47.0 (10914617)|METHOD_ENTRY|[2]|01p0a000004xIGS|DemoController.DemoController()
06:18:47.0 (10938605)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
06:18:47.0 (10973654)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2]
06:18:47.0 (11034287)|METHOD_EXIT|[2]|DemoController
06:18:47.0 (11086149)|METHOD_ENTRY|[19]|01p0a000004xIGS|DemoController.getRecords()
06:18:47.0 (11269234)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[5]
06:18:47.0 (11279588)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[7]
06:18:47.0 (11393029)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[7]|Bytes:8
06:18:47.0 (11441704)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[7]|location|String|false|false
06:18:47.0 (11481649)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[7]|location|null
06:18:47.0 (11497412)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[8]
06:18:47.0 (11561030)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[8]|Bytes:2
06:18:47.0 (11595516)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[8]|id|String|false|false
06:18:47.0 (11619080)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[8]|id|null
06:18:47.0 (11630485)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[10]
06:18:47.0 (11639122)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[10]|Bytes:56
06:18:47.0 (11658680)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[10]|qryString|String|false|false
06:18:47.0 (11686710)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[10]|qryString|"Select Id,Name,Locat (36 more) ..."
06:18:47.0 (11699375)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[12]
06:18:47.0 (11708945)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[12]|DemoGoods|List<Good__c>|true|false
06:18:47.0 (11731440)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[12]|DemoGoods|null|
06:18:47.0 (11836472)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[14]
06:18:47.0 (11889562)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[15]
06:18:47.0 (11897586)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[17]
06:18:47.0 (25045909)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[17]|Aggregations:0|Select Id,Name,Location__c from Good__c WHERE Id !=NULL 
06:18:47.0 (32135089)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[17]|Rows:0
06:18:47.0 (32188386)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:4
06:18:47.0 (32217032)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:0
06:18:47.0 (32266902)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[17]|Bytes:4
06:18:47.0 (32360676)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[17]|DemoGoods|[]|0x1b8941c1
06:18:47.0 (32385071)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[19]
06:18:47.0 (32422584)|METHOD_EXIT|[19]|01p0a000004xIGS|DemoController.getRecords()
06:18:47.0 (32442263)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[21]
06:18:47.0 (32452492)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[21]|Bytes:17
06:18:47.0 (32662907)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[21]|Bytes:21
06:18:47.0 (32701869)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|Response Body ---null
06:18:47.32 (32756002)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
06:18:47.32 (32756002)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

06:18:47.32 (32756002)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

06:18:47.0 (33831491)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|DemoControllerTest.TestBehavior()
06:18:47.0 (35213626)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

I welcome any recommendations. Thank you.

Comment: RestContext.response is not automatically deserialized in unit test. It might be necessary to collect returned List<Good__c>  from getRecords method and assert that

Answer (score 1):

You declare `demoGoods` locally, then you assign it and return it. But you never touch the `RestContext.response` in order to set it there. Your test expects you to do so.

```
DemoGoods = Database.query(qryString);
// here you need to set RestContext.response.responseBody
return DemoGoods;
```

Most likely, you will just serialize your records.

```
RestContext.response.responseBody = JSON.serialize(demoGoods);
```